# Подскажите пожалуйста почему обьект не передвигается с помощью метода (Vector3.MoveTowards)

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

первый класс.

```
public class Triggerforenemy : MonoBehaviour {
public bool Trigger = false;
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        Trigger = true;

    }
}
```

}

второй класс`{//скрипт для

```
// Цель к которой будем двигаться
public Transform target;
public Triggerforenemy hello;
// Скорость персонажа в секунду
public float speed;



void Update()
{
    if (hello.Trigger == true)
    {



        // Размер шага равен скорость * время кадра.
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;


        // Переместите нашу позицию на шаг ближе к цели.
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }
}
```

}`

По идее обьект capsule должна двигаться к обьекту персонаж но капсула почему то не движется к нему

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

все спасибо сам разобрался.target- это цель к которой должен идти обьект .А я думал ,что это сам обьект, который преследует.